# My doubled while loop isn't working. How does this work?

Tags: php, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to work with a while loop to put out some thumbnails with text, but only the first `<tr>` is working fine, the second one is not even displayed. I'm getting no errors, so I don't know what I did wrong.

```
<?php
  require_once("inc/config.inc.php");
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM games ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20";
  $result = $mysqli->query($sql);
  $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

  $counter = 0;
  $max = 5;
  $counter2 = 0;
  $max2 = 5;
?>

  <table style="table-layout:fixed;width:100%;text-align:center;" align="center" valign="center">
    <?php 
      echo "<tr>";
      while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) and ($counter < $max)) {echo "<td><a class='nogame' href='play.php?g=". $row['pid'] ."'><img src='". $tpath . $row['thumb'] ."'><br>". $row['name'] ."</a></td>";$counter++;}
      echo "</tr>";
      echo "<tr>";
      while (($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) and ($counter2 < $max2)) {echo "<td><a class='nogame' href='play.php?g=". $row['pid'] ."'><img src='". $tpath . $row['thumb'] ."'><br>". $row['name'] ."</a></td>";$counter2++;}
      echo "</tr>";
    ?>
  </table>
```

I hope you can help me. And sorry, if I did a dumb error. I'm new to PHP.
Also, I tried to google, but it didn't helped.

Greetings

Comment: You need to reset the result set between the two queries. At the end of the first while loop, the result set has no more records to return, so the loop terminates. When the second loop starts, it immediately terminates because there are no records. I suspect that `$row->data_seek(0)` between the loops will do what you want.

Comment: your first loop fetches **ALL** of the result rows. Then the second loop has nothing left to work with.

Comment: Ahh wow! Thank you both guys. `$result->data_seek(0);` fixed the problem. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well there are no apparent problems here that may cause your issue.
What may be is that there are less than 6 records in your database (6, because you "eat" one of them in row 5).
Also please see if the secound pair of tr-s are present in the page *source*. If not, your code dies for some reason.